# Edit role error 'Wrong tab configuration'

Tags: magento-1.9, user-roles

I'm not very familiar with magento code, 
Recently when I try to add/edit the user role I got following error, can anybody help me how to solve this issue.

```
Wrong tab configuration.

#0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Editroles.php(42): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab('account', false)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_Editroles->_prepareLayout()
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/permi...', 'adminhtml.permi...')
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/permi...', 'adminhtml.permi...')
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php(44): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php(105): Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_RoleController->_initAction()
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_RoleController->editRoleAction()
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('editrole')
#14 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /var/www/html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the error here:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1264aee821b451b3c88e55659cd1ee79d3b324af/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Editroles.php#L42

For some reason, the

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/permissions_tab_rolesedit','adminhtml.permissions.tab.rolesedit')
```

returns false in your shop.

Looking at here:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1264aee821b451b3c88e55659cd1ee79d3b324af/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L437

we see that this happens, when an expetion is raised during the _getBlockInstance Call

Since this Exception should get Logged, you should take a look at the last message in your var/log/exception.log

Then looking at here:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1264aee821b451b3c88e55659cd1ee79d3b324af/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L484

might give you the answer

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please describe in details ? i had same issue all other tabs working fine in magento expect add new role tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had had this same error, but I fix it recreating my file `adminhtml.xml`, you can use this below like a sample and changing the necessary tags, **that are line 11, 12 and 14** to your custom module name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <YOURVENDOR_YOURMODULE>
                                        <title>YOURMODULE</title>
                                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                                    </YOURVENDOR_YOURMODULE>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```